# reload XmlDataSource DataFile in C# for Gridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview, xmldatasource

```
XmlDataSource1.DataFile = @"C:\test.xml";
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I am changing the file data (test.xml) multiple times and reloading it into xmldatasource using above code but gridview just displays data of first(unchanged) test.xml file .

Comment: How do you associate XmlDataSource1 with the GridView1?

Comment: In design code: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5857577/49251, your XmlDataSource1 may have caching enabled, so it might not re-read the file.

Comment: Sounds right but didn't work for me.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387894/how-to-bind-xml-elements-to-the-gridview-using-the-xmldatasourse

Comment: thanks but Not working .